# how to use WebView Control in Windows phone 8 C# app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, webview

I'm currently using:

```
WebBrowserTask:-
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute);
webBrowserTask.Show();
```

Like that.
It will go to google page but after that when i go form next or next to next page by google, Then i want to get url of that page.
But i couldn't get it. 
WebView Provide it in Windows Phone 8.1. but my app is only in wp 8 and i want solution in WP8.

Please Help...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431797(v=vs.105).aspx) control?

Just add in in your xaml and start using it, with it you have much more control and you can get the current url

Comment: but my server auto redirect from one url to another and that is not done in web control...  I just call one url but there is another 1 or 2 urls get by server & it auto redirect to these url....   I want to get that last url